# Looping through xml with php, can't get image:title and url in same array

Tags: php, xml

I'm just looking to loop through this xml and echo each object
I've been able to do them separately but would like each  in a foreach

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
foreach ($xml->url as $url_list) 
{
$url = $url_list->loc; 
echo $url; //works
$image_title = $url_list->image:title; 
echo $image_title; ///doesn't work
//would also like to get other 4 objects lastmod,changefreq,image:loc
}





    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/collections/xxx</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-02-04T17:35:40-05:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <image:image>
    <image:loc>https://example.com/collections/xxx.png?v=1582857057</image:loc>
    <image:title>xxx</image:title>
    </image:image>
    </url>
    <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/collections/yyy</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-02-04T22:50:40-05:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <image:image>
    <image:loc>https://example.com/collections/yyy.png?v=1582858125</image:loc>
    <image:title>yyy</image:title>
    </image:image>
    </url>
```

Comment: use `$image_title = $url_list->title;`, or `$lastmod = $url_list->lastmod;`, or `$changefreq = $url_list->changefreq;`

Comment: Thanks for the input that doesn't work either, do I need to use registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1');

Comment: seems to work just [fine](https://3v4l.org/HXF7s)

Comment: Doesn't work in you example @berend the title isn't being echoed, this is the exact problem